# После изменения размера окна кнопка/текст исчезают

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2012

В "Maximized" все видно, в измененном пользователем размере формы уже сужается кнопка (Скриншот 1), А если совсем сжать, то она вообще пропадает. Как настроить это дело так, чтобы и в измененном пользователем размере и в "Maximized" выглядело почти одинаково?

[image: [![][1]]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код кнопки и текста:

```
namespace -----
{
partial class MainScreen
    {
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this.label1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)));
        this.label1.AutoSize = true;
        this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 51);
        this.label1.Name = "label1";
        this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(38, 13);
        this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.label1.Text = "Логин";
        // 
        // label2
        // 
        this.label2.AutoSize = true;
        this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(37, 73);
        this.label2.Name = "label2";
        this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(42, 13);
        this.label2.TabIndex = 1;
        this.label2.Text = "Группа";
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this.button1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)));
        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 901);
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(104, 89);
        this.button1.TabIndex = 2;
        this.button1.Text = "test";
        this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
        // 
        // MainScreen
        // 
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Inherit;
        this.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1904, 1002);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        this.Name = "MainScreen";
        this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        this.Text = "Test";
        this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.LoadUserData_Load);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
}
}
```

Comment: Добавьте код, того как у Вы реализовали кнопку и прочее. Иначе понять в чем проблему будет тяжело.

Comment: @Dejsving Т.к я новичек, я сразу скажу, что делал не в WPF, поэтому как-то так... Vusial C# не выдает код... Ну а вообще...         private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;

Comment: > "Vusial C# не выдает код"

Кто вам такое сказал? откройте файл: Form1.Designer.cs 
Там находится весь код дизайнера

Comment: @Chloroform Добавил в вопрос

Comment: Ну `Anchor` настройте правильно

Comment: @Андрей Удивительно, но помогло, несмотря на то, что я их уже и так и сяк настраивал. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в Anchor. Настроил на Top,Left и заработало.