# Премещение кнопки при наведении мыши на кнопку

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2012

Как можно при наведении мыши на кнопку перемещать ее (так же, только еще в обратную сторону нужно)?
Этот код криво справляется. Т.к. при небольшом перемещении (например на 20 по Y) он обрезает половину кнопки, а если больше (например, 120 по Y) кнопка вообще исчезает из виду.
В идеале, кнопка должна быть картинкой получаемой с сервера при наведении мышки на которую, должна плавно выезжать Panel в которой будет несколько текстов (ссылки). Я думаю если подставить под кнопку Panel и сделать к ней событие ухода мышки то будет вполне отлично, т.к. панель будет появлятся при наведении мышки на кнопку

```
        private void button1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Location = new Point(button1.Location.X, button1.Location.Y - 150);
    }

    private void button1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Location = new Point(button1.Location.X, button1.Location.Y + 150);

    }
```

---

[image: Форма в подробном описании]

Код формы:

```
namespace -------
{
partial class MainScreen
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager(typeof(MainScreen));
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this.label1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)));
        this.label1.AutoSize = true;
        this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 51);
        this.label1.Name = "label1";
        this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(38, 13);
        this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.label1.Text = "Логин";
        // 
        // label2
        // 
        this.label2.AutoSize = true;
        this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(37, 73);
        this.label2.Name = "label2";
        this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(42, 13);
        this.label2.TabIndex = 1;
        this.label2.Text = "Группа";
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this.button1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Bottom | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left)));
        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 777);
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 100);
        this.button1.TabIndex = 2;
        this.button1.Text = "test";
        this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.button1.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_MouseEnter);
        this.button1.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_MouseLeave);
        // 
        // MainScreen
        // 
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.None;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1264, 889);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        this.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon")));
        this.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1024, 576);
        this.Name = "MainScreen";
        this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        this.Text = "Test";
        this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.LoadUserData_Load);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
}
}
```

Comment: хм, добавьте в подписчики вывод лога куда-нибудь в `Label`. Я думаю, что проблема в том, что первое событие сдвигает кнопку, она находится теперь не под курсором, поэтому срабатывает второе событие, которое возвращает кнопку назад и так по кругу. Или отключите сначала второе событие и посмотрите как себя ведет кнопка

Comment: @Андрей Да, теперь она не исчезает

Comment: Остается теперь вместо второго события придумать что-то получше

Comment: @Андрей В идеале, кнопка должна быть картинкой получаемой с сервера при наведении мышки на которую, должна плавно выезжать Panel в которой будет несколько текстов (ссылки). Я думаю если подставить под кнопку Panel и сделать к ней событие ухода мышки то будет вполне отлично, т.к. панель будет появлятся при наведении мышки на кнопку

Comment: Можете объяснить для чего вообще планировалось использовать `Mouse_Leave`? То ли я чего-то не понимаю, то ли у Вас есть какие-то еще требования.

Comment: @defaultlocale , Все слишком сложно. При наведении на что либо открывавлся список ссылок, а если убрать мышь с этого "чего-либо" то ссылки должны закрываться

Comment: Т.е. в текущей формулировке вопроса и в демонстрационном проекте (где только одна кнопка) без `Mouse_Leave` можно обойтись?

Comment: Попробуйте расписать требования поподробнее. Судя по всему Вы хотите чтобы кнопка возвращалась на место. Это нужно написать в тексте вопроса, при этом уточнить когда именно кнопка должна возвращаться назад.

Comment: А зачем вы вообще делаете это на кнопке? Судя по вашему описанию - берете панель, выставляете у нее Dock в нужную сторону, по событию Enter - увеличиваете ширину, по событию Leave - уменьшаете. Перенесите описание решаемой задачи из комментариев вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Установите значение свойства `Anchor` равным None.

Comment: А теперь главная загвоздка! Без Anchor кнопка не будет привязываться к окну, и в последствии при изменении размера окна пользователем оно будет "Обрезаться" (Исчезать [Stackoverflow на русском, вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/718200/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82)) но в том же случае нужно перемещать эту кнопку.

Comment: Кстати, Anchor - None тоже не дает результата. все равно исчезает, а при клике появляется (и снова исчезает)

Comment: Тогда нужно больше деталей о вашей форме. Можете скриншот к вопросу прикрепить.